# How to configure already statically routed IPv6 block on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, centos7, ipv6, networkmanager

My question is very simple yet I didn't find a solution, probably because of my lack of networking knowledge.

I have a dedicated server and I manipulate it through IPMI remotely. Recently I asked for IPv6 support from the administrator here is what I got
respond

`IP Range: 2604:881:39c::/48 has been statically routed to your server.`
I tried to assign an IP within this block (`2604:881:39c::2`) to my server then I found they didn't provide gateway address. Then I asked

> Me: Can I ask what is the ipv6 gateway address?
>   Admin: This is a static route and does not include a gateway. All IPs are routed to your server.

I tried to configure it but I have totally no idea what the right path is. Because I don't know much about IPv6 addressing and what this "STATIC ROUTE" on upstream means here. What I have got so far is I randomly pick an address `2604:881:39c::2` and set `2604:881:39c::1` to be the gateway. Here:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eno1
UUID=6d049769-68a1-4631-83d4-46b0f3afdf59
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=XX.XXX.XX.XX
PREFIX=30
GATEWAY=XX.XXX.XX.XX
DNS1=8.8.8.8
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
ZONE=public
DNS2=2001:4860:4860::8888
IPV6ADDR=2604:881:39c::2/48
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=2604:881:39c::1
IPV6_PEERROUTES=no
```

When I do `tracepath6`, I have:

```
PING ipv6.google.com(dfw28s04-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4000:815::200e)) 56 data bytes
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=5 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=6 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=7 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From myhostname (2604:881:39c::2) icmp_seq=8 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

It seems like it resolved the DNS successfully but had no route to the global internet. Also, I tried `ip -6 route add` but it didn't work.

Does anyone have ideas about this? I am stuck.

Comment: Now ask the network admin to stop joking and give you the real gateway address.

Comment: Simply use the [Subnet-Router anycast address](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.6.1) for the gateway.

Comment: @RonMaupin Assuming the router actually responds to that address. It ought to, but it might not.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, then there is a problem with the network because, "_All routers are required to support the Subnet-Router anycast addresses for the subnets to which they have interfaces._"

Answer (score 2):

If the network admin really refuses to give you the gateway address, you can just ping the IPv6 all routers multicast address, and it will respond. You will then know at least one of its addresses.

For example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping6 -c 1 ff02::2%eno1
PING ff02::2%eno1(ff02::2%eno1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::5054:ff:fefc:d4da%eno1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.265 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

An IPv6 /48 prefix is an awfully big block of addresses to assign to a single host. However, I'm going to disregard that for now and give you some suggestions.

1. Try IPv6 autoconf. One of the nice things about IPv6 is that, except for certain use cases, you shouldn't need to define manual configs. Here is an example config that enables autoconf based on the config you provided:

   ```
   # IPv6 autoconf example
   TYPE=Ethernet
   PROXY_METHOD=none
   BROWSER_ONLY=no
   BOOTPROTO=none
   DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   IPV6INIT=yes
   IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
   IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=eui64
   NAME=eno1
   UUID=6d049769-68a1-4631-83d4-46b0f3afdf59
   DEVICE=eno1
   ONBOOT=yes
   IPADDR=XX.XXX.XX.XX
   PREFIX=30
   GATEWAY=XX.XXX.XX.XX
   DNS1=8.8.8.8
   IPV6_PRIVACY=no
   ZONE=public
   DNS2=2001:4860:4860::8888
   ```
2. See if you can determine the local router's address by looking at your neighbor tables:

   ```
   # ip -4 neighbor show
   # ip -6 neighbor show
   ```

   You should see the IP and MAC address of your IPv4 gatway in the -4 neighbor table. Then, look for the same MAC address in the output of the -6 neighbor table. There may be multiple IPv6 addresses with that MAC - this is OK. The one starting with `fe80::` is the link-local address of the router, and is perfectly good to use. Otherwise, you may see another address that is in the same block that you were allocated, and you can use that as your IPv6 gateway instead with your static configuration.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply but auto mode doesn't work. It has to be the manual configuration apparently.

Answer (score 0):

On my VPS, the default gateway is defined as:

```
IPV6_DEFAULTGW="fe80::1%eth0"
```

On my home network, it is:

```
IPV6_DEFAULTGW="fe80::218:7dff:fe05:dd11%eth0"
```

`fe80::/10` are link-local addresses and are based on the MAC address of the network interface of the gateway device. In the case of my VPS, they've just gone with `fe80::1` as everything is virtual.

Michael Hampton's answer looks to be correct, and I've upvoted it. If you follow his advice, you should get back an `fe80::*` address - set this as your default gateway, post-fixing the `%interface-name` on the end, and you should be good to go.